# I have to remove u' in all the list items

Tags: python, django

[u'bangladesh', u'bhutan', u'maldives', u'nepal', u'sri lanka', u'united arab emirates', u'hong kong', u'malaysia', u'singapore', u'thailand', u'china', u'bahrain', u'iran (islamic republic of)', u'jordan', u'kuwait']

I dont want the u' in every item.

Comment: I don't know why not, but if you don't want it, `return list(map(str, HttpResponse(a)))`

Comment: It's high time to move to Python 3. Common, it's been 8 years since it was first released.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. Apart from anything else, that *still* wouldn't be valid JSON, because it has single quotes.

If you want JSON, you should ask for JSON.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(a))
```

Comment: I have to remove the duplicates in the list too before converting it into JSON

Comment: OK, so why don't you do that?

Comment: What? I tried that by converting it into set but it says unhashable error

Comment: Is there something you can help me with?

Comment: No, because that is too vague. Exactly what did you try, and exactly what error did you get? And that is a separate question; if I have answered this one, accept it and ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The u is just informational, meaning that the texts are unicode.

```
>>> country
[u'bangladesh', u'bhutan', u'maldives', u'nepal', u'sri lanka', u'united arab emirates', u'hong kong', u'malaysia', u'singapore', u'thailand', u'china', u'bahrain', u'iran (islamic republic of)', u'jordan', u'kuwait']
>>> for c in country:
...     print c
... 
bangladesh
bhutan
maldives
nepal
sri lanka
united arab emirates
hong kong
malaysia
singapore
thailand
china
bahrain
iran (islamic republic of)
jordan
kuwait
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(country)
'["bangladesh", "bhutan", "maldives", "nepal", "sri lanka", "united arab emirates", "hong kong", "malaysia", "singapore", "thailand", "china", "bahrain", "iran (islamic republic of)", "jordan", "kuwait"]'
>>>
```

So, you don't have to do anything, you just misunderstood what the u means

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to remove u' from every item just replace the line

```
....
a.append(list_country[i])
...
```

by

```
....
a.append(str(list_country[i]))
....
```